# How does this op-amp circuit for GFCI fault detection work?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, capacitor, current, rectifier

Can someone explain how the op-amp circuit in section 4.2 *GFCI Fault Detection and Test*, page 14 of this [application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidub87/tidub87.pdf?ts=1686893017696&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) works?

[image]

I am unable to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. the document you linked describes it adequately in the paragraph right underneath it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In the second line of the paragraph, it is mentioned " A discharge path", can you tell me what is the discharge path? 2. Is the signal in GFCI+, an AC signal? 3. Why is there a diode in output of both the op-amps?

Comment: @Freshman When the ground fault goes away, and U3A output falls low again, D5 becomes reverse biased, effectively disconnecting the op-amp output from C3. Then C3 is free to discharge via R59,  R10 and R14. That's the only discharge path I can identify.

Comment: @Freshman "R14 acts as a burden resistor to the current transformer" tells us that the signal is indeed an AC current, being converted to a voltage by R14.